# Jquery each no funciona

Tags: javascript, jquery

Buenas estoy creando un shoping cart y estoy usando DCAJAXPaypalCart pero no se agregan los datos por cada clase de spoc que encuentre.

[DCAJAXPaypalCart](http://livedocs.digicrafts.com.hk/examples/JSAJAXPayPalCart/)  aca les dejo de donde esta el ejemplo del shoping cart

```
 $(function () {
    var cart = $('#cart').DCAJAXPaypalCart({
        width: 800,
        openNewCheckOutWindow: true,
        //themeColor:'#333',
        //themeDarkColor:'#FFF',
        header: 'AJAX Cart Demo',
        footer: 'We accpet paypal, visa and master card. (This is a customizable footer)',
        paypalOptions: {
            business: 'tsangwl@digicrafts.com.hk',

        }

    });

    $('.spoc').each(function (index, element) {
        alert($(this).attr('data-id') + "  " + $(this).attr('data-name') + " " + $(this).attr('data-price') + " " + $(this).attr('data-image'));
        cart.addBuyButton('#' + $(this).attr('data-id'), {
            id: $(this).attr('data-id'),
            name: $(this).attr('data-name'),                     // Item name appear on the cart
            thumbnail: 'imgs/llantas_menu/' + $(this).attr('data-image'),      // Thumbnail path of the item (Optional)
            price: $(this).attr('data-price')                     // Cost of the item
            // Shipping cost for the item (Optional)

        });
        return cart;
    });

});
```

Comment: ¿Puedes agregar el html de la pagina para ayudarte mejor?

Comment: No entendí el título, podrías expresarlo mejor?

Answer (score 0):

Hay un error conceptual en tu lógica. ¿Por qué estás ejecutando la función "addBuyButton" (esto es, "agregar botón de compra") en el evento click de otro botón? Eso es terrible: estás agregando un botón cada vez que apretás el botón.

No: los addBuyButton los agregás en el evento load de la página, y luego el usuario usa esos botones para comprar cosas.

No conozco este plugin, pero sospecho que podés hacer algo como esto:

```js
$(function () {
    var cart = $('#cart').DCAJAXPaypalCart({
        width: 800,
        openNewCheckOutWindow: true,
        //themeColor:'#333',
        //themeDarkColor:'#FFF',
        header: 'AJAX Cart Demo',
        footer: 'We accpet paypal, visa and master card. (This is a customizable footer)',
        paypalOptions: {
            business: 'tsangwl@digicrafts.com.hk',

        }

    });
    
    $('.button').each(function() {
        cart.addBuyButton('#' + $(this).attr('data-id'), {
            id: $(this).attr('data-id'),
            name: $(this).attr('data-name'),                     // Item name appear on the cart
            thumbnail: 'imgs/llantas_menu/' + $(this).attr('data-image'),      // Thumbnail path of the item (Optional)
            price: $(this).attr('data-price')                     // Cost of the item
            // Shipping cost for the item (Optional)

        });

    });

});
```

Comment: tienes toda la razon lo edite ya pero ahora el each no entra a mi funcion no genera el codigo que quiero para cada uno de los botones.  https://jsfiddle.net/Godeolo/5kuma715/ te dejo la parte de mi codigo por si me puedes ayudar a revisarlo